# Type clash expression of type int * int cannot have type int * int * int on SML

Tags: sml, mosml

I'm trying to make a code on Moscow ML/SML about magic squares. Whenever I try to run the code, I always get this error on line 15:

```
! Type clash: expression of type
!   int * int
! cannot have type
!   int * int * int
! because the tuple has the wrong number of components
```

With the following line being the problem constantly:
`else place_number (next_position (i, j)) num m`

Here's the complete function that places a number in a position within the square:

```
    fun place_number (i, j, num) m =
      if Array.sub(Array.sub(m, i), j) = 0 then
        (Array.update(Array.sub(m, i), j, num); m)
      else place_number (next_position (i, j)) num m
```

I've tried to use different implementations of it but it pretty much results on the same error. A few are:

`else place_number (next_position (i, j)) num m`

`else place_number (next_position (i, j)) num`

`else place_number (next_position (i, j)) num (m)`

Comment: Can you provide the `next_position` function as well?

Comment: Also note that you specify `place_number` as taking two arguments, but in your recursive call you supply _three_.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition says that `place_number` takes two arguments; a triple `(i, j, num)` and `m`.

Then you try to call it with three arguments; `(next_position (i, j))`, `num`, and `m`.

Assuming that `next_position` has the type `int * int -> int * int`, you need to deconstruct its result first and then make a triple with the parts:

```
fun place_number (i, j, num) m =
    if Array.sub(Array.sub(m, i), j) = 0 then
        (Array.update(Array.sub(m, i), j, num); m)
    else 
        let val (i', j') = next_position (i, j)
          in place_number (i', j', num) m
        end
```

but it's more convenient to change the function's type:

```
fun place_number (i, j) num m =
      if Array.sub(Array.sub(m, i), j) = 0 then
        (Array.update(Array.sub(m, i), j, num); m)
      else place_number (next_position (i, j)) num m
```